# Critical dimension of ${\cal N}=2$ strings

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, quantum-anomalies

In "A tour through ${\cal N}=2$ strings" by Neil Marcus (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9211059) the following problem - among others - is noted:

The critical dimension of the ${\cal N}=2$ string is 4, as it can be seen from the central charge $$c=-26+2 \cdot 11-2=-6$$ or from the partition function $$Z_{string}=\frac1{4\pi}\int_{\mathcal{M}} \frac{d^2\tau}{\tau_2^{D/2}} $$
which is modular invariant in $D=4$ only.

On the other hand, the corresponding field theory calculation yields $$Z=\frac12 \frac1{(4\pi)^{D/2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{s^{1+D/2}}e^{-sm^2}$$
which suggests that the critical dimension is $D=2$.

This review is now almost 30 years old, so, has this been resolved by now? It appears to me that the interest in ${\cal N}=2$ strings has pretty much died. If true, why?

Answer (score 4):

It think there are no rational arguments about why people stopped to be interested in $\mathcal{N}=2$ strings. They are arguably as important as the $\mathcal{N}=1$ ones.

However, I will enumerate some possible "sociological" reasons of why this unfortunate lack of interest.

1. **The precise relation with $\mathcal{N}=1$ superstrings is not clear.** Despite of the fact that N=1 strings can be proved to be twisted versions of the N=2 case (see [The N=1 superstring as a topological field theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405039) and [On the uniqueness of string theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9310170#:%7E:text=We%20show%20that%20bosonic%20strings,vacua%20for%20N%3D2%20strings.)); it's not clear at all what is the physical significance of the N=2 vacua. The reason for this is that N=2 strings induce self-dual gravity as its target space gravity and this seems to be unrelated to our observations about gravity. This is connected with the fact that N=2 strings can only consistently propagate on target spacetimes with (++--) or (++++) signatures, and of course, it is difficult to make physical sense of this.
2. **N=2 strings have been of enormous importance for the topological string development but topological string theory is not as "popular" as the physical superstring.** N=2 strings were important for the discovery of S-dualties among topological A and B models and many interesting developments in integrability and unification in the context of non-critical string theories (see [N=2 strings and the twistorial Calabi-Yau](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0402128) and [S-duality and topoligical strings](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0403167)). The problem is that not much people is aware of the significance of topological strings in the context of physical superstrings and again, its difficult to decide whether N=2 strings are on the same footing that the N=1 strings or not.

Despite of the aforementioned reasons, there are also important and widely overlooked hints and programs that indicate that N=2 and N=4 superstrings may be of fundamental importance to understand string theory as a whole.

1. I highly recommend the wonderful blog post [Worldsheets and spacetimes: kinship and cross-pollination](https://motls.blogspot.com/2014/05/worldsheets-and-spacetimes-kinship-and.html) for some speculations on the importance of N=2 strings to understand string theory in its full generality.
2. [A tour through N=2 strings](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9211059)
3. [New Principles for String/Membrane Unification](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9602049)

Comment: Do any of these sources address the critical dimension part of the question?

Comment: @NiharKarve No, as far as I know. This is still an unsolved issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the insights and links you provided are really interesting!